# Player de audio HTML 5 com avançar/retroceder

Tags: html5, html5-audio

Estou trabalhando em um player em HTML 5 e tive uma triste surpresa ao tentar usar o recurso de avançar/retroceder quando coloco o cursor em determinado minuto da musica (como fazemos no youtube, por exemplo).

```
<audio id="AudioApresentacao" controls="controls" preload="none">

        <source id="urlAudio" type="audio/mpeg" src="ARQUIVO DE AUDIO" /></audio>
```

Acontece que ao colocar um áudio com poucos minutos, como uma música, isso funciona normalmente. Porém o áudio que estou carregando tem cerca de 80 minutos! E este recurso não funciona. Alguém conhece uma solução pra isso?

Testado no Chrome e no IE11.

Comment: Olá Tiago! Bem vindo ao SOePT. Poderias ser mais claro ao dizer "não funciona", e especificar em quais browsers você constatou o problema? Também seria legal postar a parte do código do seu player que você acredita estar com problema.

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pelas boas-vindas! @FabrícioMatté testei no Chrome e no IE. O que quis dizer com "não funciona" é que ao colocar o cursor em determinado minuto da musica (como fazemos no youtube, por exemplo) ele não adianta/volta para o ponto que quero.

Comment: Sempre prefira tornar sua pergunta mais clara através da edição. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/700/como-comecar-aqui-no-stackoverflow-em-portugues

Comment: @bigown editado! Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Apenas um palpite: Pode ter algo haver com o tamanho do arquivo e com o browser ainda o estar baixando. Você tentou localmente? (talvez ele faça streaming mesmo sendo local)

Comment: Uma solução é você dividir o arquivo em vários menores, e colocar eles pra tocar em sequencia, fazendo uma seekbar personalizada com tempo total do seu audio, sendo calculando a posição que está qual dos arquivos deve ser usado. Assim seu browser consegue interromper o download de parte da música e começa a carregar a outra parte necessária para a posição que você deseja.

Comment: @GabrielGartz Eu acho que isso já foi implementado pela maioria dos browsers: Partial Content. O problema é: o servidor suporta isso? Se "ARQUIVO DE AUDIO === download.php" ou algo parecido, eis o problema.

Comment: Também li pela internet que várias APIs que manipulam arquivos de audio estão tendo problemas com limites de memória, mas no caso eu acho que é porque eles convertem o arquivo de MP3 em um blob pra poder manipular local e ai passa a consumir memória, já sobre arquivos grandes o ultimo relato foi Chrome 13 que travava, fora isso eu concordo contigo @GustavoRodrigues, se o servidor não suportar partial download tem que fazer uma solução alternativa, ou aguardar o download completo do arquivo.

Comment: Só vi isso ocorrer quando o arquivo precisava ser manipulado (WebAudio) ou quando a API era de um codec feito em javascript (http://audiocogs.org/codecs/mp3/). Na maioria dos casos que já mexi elas só usam tags <audio> e/ou flash: a parte mais técnica fica a cargo do navegador (ou flash).

Answer (score 2):

O caminho mais curto é você utilizar um servidor de streaming para o usuario pular para alguma parte do audio que não foi feita o download e iniciar o download para o ponto que ele deseja.

Para não investir em sofwares/servidor de streaming tente utilizar o Http Live Streaming (para ao vivo e gravado) ou pesquise softwares como WOWZA, FMS ou RED5.

Flowplayer tem a opção de [Pseudistreaming](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html), um pouco mais complexo.

Usando o flowplayer você pode chamar o metodo seek() para pular para uma determinada parte do video.

```
$f().seek(valorEmSegundos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo você olhar o **flowplayer**, ele é muito bom e caso o browser não suporte html5 ele faz [fallback para flash](https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html#flash)!

http://flowplayer.org/

Usei ele no projeto da JovemPan FM que entrou no ar dia (02/02/2014): http://jovempanfm.uol.com.br/